# Session.Remove(Key) Throwing null refrence exception

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, session-state

I am getting following error in my aspx.cs page during adding one item in session

```
Session["request_params"]=new Hashtable();
```

Argument exception

Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'request_params'  Key being added: 'request_params'

But as per as my understanding adding or updating value to session never throw any exception.

I am using InProc  Session mode.

Any suggestion from any one.

Comment: this might be of some help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2008/06/21/argumentexception-when-adding-objects-in-session-item-has-already-been-added-to-the-dictionary.aspx

Comment: 10 years later, I have the same issue, even after I added lock around the area...